# draw a circular arc in MXML Graphics

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, flex4, mxml

Is there a simple way to draw a circular arc in MXML graphics that doesn't involve beziers? Or should I create my own component?

thank you !

f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating my own mxml graphics component to draw arcs. I override Ellipse Spark primitive and use AS for the arc math - mostly copying [this great post](http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=429), which points to [this code](http://code.google.com/p/leebrimelow/source/browse/trunk/as3/com/theflashblog/drawing/Arc.as).

Answer (score 2):

```
<s:Ellipse height="16" width="16">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" joints="square" caps="square"/>
    </s:stroke>
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0x000000"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Ellipse>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw curves using the `Path` class. You set its `data` property as a string containing alternating commands and numeric values that execute cursor placement and drawing operations. The commands are:

- C - Draws a bezier curve.
- H - Draws a horizontal line.
- L - Draws a line.
- M - Moves cursor.
- Q - Draws a quadratic bezier curve.
- V - Draws a vertical line.
- Z - Closes path.

An example of how to use this with FXG is as follows:

```
<s:Path data="M 20 0
        C 50 0 50 35 20 35
        L 15 35 L 15 45
        L 0 32 L 15 19
        L 15 29 L 20 29
        C 44 29 44 6 20 6">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" weight="1"/>
    </s:stroke> 
</s:Path>
```

You can find more infomation on it here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS5B6A8436-0FF5-4029-8524-C7C1106C483D.html

Comment: right - thank you. So the issue with this is that it seems like this is all through Beziers, which generally don't do such a great job at circle arcs. So I'm guessing no circle arcs directly in MXML from what I can gather on google and here. I'm wondering if I need to write my own class in AS and then write use it in MXML. I guess that's the path I'll go down unless I hear any other more amazing idea. Anyway, thank you for your reply!

Comment: sorry, no - the question is there is a way that doesn't involved beziers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. If it makes sense to enclose the code for drawing in a seperate class is up to you and is a question of software arcitecture.

Drawing curves can you manage with the drawing api. check this out [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd9.html)

BR Frank

*EDIT:20.02.2011 - 21:12*
Another idea without beziers can be the math class. Here is a liitle example to draw a sine curve [Link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd9.html)

Comment: Frank, thanks for your answer. Doesn't look like MXML graphics though. Also, looks like this is all through Beziers - no direct circle arc...

Comment: how do you want draw curves without beziers? What is the goal for your arc and why do you looking for a solution without beziers? Another possibility can be to draw curves point by point.

Comment: would love to draw a circular arc (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry). You shouldn't need beziers for that - in fact beziers don't do a perfect job at drawing circles.